# I thought PNG had better file compression than gif in terms of size. Then why is my PNG larger than my gif? I used pycharm to convert file

Tags: python, image, compression, png, gif

The Code I used to convert BMP to GIF

[click here to view the image formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CShIq.png)

The Code I used to convert BMP to GIF

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
# Create the frames
frames = []
imgs = glob.glob("*.bmp")
for i in imgs:
    new_frame = Image.open(i)
    frames.append(new_frame)

# Save into a GIF file that loops forever
frames[0].save('bmp_to_gif.gif', format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               duration=300, loop=0)
```

BMP to PNG

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open("sample_1920×1280.bmp").save("sample1.png")
```

Comment: Where did you get the notion that pngs should be smaller than gifs? This depends entirely on the source material.

Comment: It's not really an equal comparison, generating an animated GIF of images of unknown size (to us) versus a single image.

Comment: Is the resulting color depth the same in both cases?

Comment: @sj95126 Look at the image attached I have shown my gif with its file size. And the gif is just 1 frame.

Comment: If you share your BMP, GIF and PNG images (via Dropbox or Google Drive or similar) it might be easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSG No it's not my png file is in 24 bits. WIll it work if I change it to 8 bits?

Comment: `WIll it work if` is the question you never ask here. do it and let us know the result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

GIF is palletizing the image down to 256 colors. Your PNG compression is not, retaining all of the original colors, which I'm guessing is RGB.

You can convert it to palette after opening the BMP using `img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)`. When saving to PNG, use `optimize=True`.